# Doing ->save to multiple relations

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I am using Laravel 5.5.13.

I have a model called `Thumb`. This thumb is related to two things in a many-to-one relationship: `Player` and `Comment`.

I currently do things like this:

```
public function store(Request $request, Entity $entity, Player $player)
{
    $thumb = new Thumb($request->all());
    $thumb->player_id = $player->id;
    $entity->thumbs()->save($thumb);
    return response()->json($thumb, 201);
}
```

We see how I have to set `$thumb->player_id` AND I don't have to set the `entity_id` because I am doing `$entity->thumbs()->save`

Is there a way to do `$entityAndPlayer->thumbs()->save`? Or is the way I did it above the recommend way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use relationships to set 2 foreign columns so they way you showed is the correct one. However you can make it a bit cleaner in my opinion.

Into `Thumb` model you could add:

```
public function setPlayer(Player $player) 
{
     $this->player_id = $player->id;
}
```

and then instead of:

```
$thumb->player_id = $player->id;
```

you could use:

```
$thumb->setPlayer($player);
```

Or you could add create `setPlayerAttribute` method and finally instead of:

```
$thumb = new Thumb($request->all());
$thumb->player_id = $player->id;
```

use just:

```
$thumb = new Thumb($request->all() + ['player' => $player]);
```

Comment: I learned a lot from this post! Especially adding two arrays that is really really super cool! I had no idea! `$request->all() + ['player' => $player]` thank you sir!

Answer (score 1):

You can't save multiple relationships at once but, for many to one associations you can use the method `associate()` ([Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models)) to save  using the **belongs to** part of the relationship, for example:

```
public function store(Request $request, Entity $entity, Player $player)
{
    $thumb = new Thumb($request->all());
    $thumb = $thumb->save();

    $thumb->player()->associate($player);
    $thumb->entity()->associate($entity);

    return response()->json($thumb, 201);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andre, my relation was one-to-many so I don't have the `attach` :(